# Updating to Windows 10 with OEM Windows 7 pro

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, oem

A technician worked on my HP Probook running Windows 7 pro and installed an OEM OS without telling me. I didn't find out until I tried to upgrade to Windows 10. I have the key for the old license on the COA. Can I still upgrade without re-buying the license for 7, or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1):

It depends, by OEM do you mean the technician installed a pirated copy? Did you download the "**Get Windows 10**" application and it's not letting you update telling you your copy is pirated or why is it failing? A few months ago *Get Windows 10* was updating even pirated copies of Windows 7 into fully legal Windows 10. I don't know if it's still doing this, or whether this was intentional. It could be in line with Microsoft's policies to get as many people to use 10 as fast as possible. Also, if the OEM is not working do you have your old system to reinstall? If you have the product key, you can also download a CD from Microsoft to reinstall your old system, in case the OEM doesn't work.

Comment: The last time I tried was Nov. last year. I tried numerous times to download Win 10 using Get Win 10 and I just kept getting the message either "download failed" or when it finally downloaded it doesn't give me the opportunity to activate. I have the restore disk, but I understand that it  will reset my computer to "new" status and wipe out everything I have installed. (The OEM is still working). I read somewhere that if the original OEM was updated the site will not allow the update as it reads the key from the ROM. I checked the key in ROM and it does not match the COA key.

Comment: I would try to find the log files for the Win 10 updater and see why it's failing, try google to see where they could be, once you have a log file message you can google that and may find a solution. If could be a log file or it could be in the Message Console of Windows.